# Applying for a Schengen visa in a jurisdiction different from where the passport is issued

Tags: schengen

I'm applying for Schengen visa through the Austrian Embassy. I no longer live in the city where my passport was issued. I've moved to a different city 8 months ago. So I'm applying in the city where I'm currently living. Will there be any problems? And should I provide any additional documents like my rent agreement?

Comment: What kind of schengen visa are you planning to apply? Which country?   What you mean by different city then passport issued city? pls. clarify your question.

Comment: Tourist visa. Passport is issued in New Delhi. I'm living in Pune now so I'm applying through here. Applying to Austrian Embassy as I've already mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 2):

The [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412) requires applicants to apply to the consulate *in whose jurisdiction they reside.*  The place of issue of the passport is not relevant.

This is controlled by article 6, which reads in full:

> Article 6
>
> Consular territorial competence
>
> 1. An application shall be examined and decided on by the consulate of the competent Member State in whose jurisdiction the applicant legally resides.
> 2. A consulate of the competent Member State shall examine and decide on an application lodged by a third-country national legally present but not residing in its jurisdiction, if the applicant has provided justification for lodging the application at that consulate.

If you reside in Pune, therefore, you must apply in Pune.  This is true even if your passport was issued in New Delhi or in Ottawa.  In fact, if you were to apply in New Delhi, they should reject your application with instructions to apply in Pune.

Comment: This Answer is not true (OP asked about austrian Embassy in India) . If you live in Pune you can also apply visa for example  in Banglore (personal experience of a freind). Because Austrian Embassy has only office in delhi. So you have to use  outsourcing & technology services specialist like VFS or you travel to delhi. For VFS it doesn't matter in which city you apply. They send all the applications to delhi. At the end  they decide in delhi which can take about 7-14 days.